# Let $M$ and $N$ be modules, definition of $M \otimes N$

Tags: tensor-products

The usual construction is via the quotient by quotienting out the subspace $D$ with these desired properties (WLOG swap x for y) where $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$

1. $(x + x',y) - (x,y) - (x',y)$
2. $(ax,y) - a(x,y)$

The notations are little confusing for me. I keep thinking the first property comes out to $(0,-y)$ and that's why we need to quotient it out because the elements of the tensor product should be bilinear maps. Hence, I am sure I can't perform subtraction like that.

I also read somewhere we are really looking at the basis elements

$$e_{(x+x',y)}(n,m)  = 1$$ if $(n,m) = (x + x',y)$ and $0$ otherwise. But these still doesn't justify the problem that $1 = e_{(x + x',y)}(x + x',y) = e_{(x + x',y)}(x,y) + e_{(x + x',y)}(x',0) = 0$

Comment: In the free module on $M\times N$, you can't combine things componentwise. So something like $(x+x',y)-(x,y)-(x',y)$ cannot be simplified at all.

Comment: @anon, well I took $X = \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $Y = \mathbb{Z}_3$, and somehow that still came out inconsistent.

Comment: The tensor product $M\otimes N$ essentially has "pretend" products of things in $M$ and $N$. The "multiplication" is denoted with the symbol $\otimes$. Hence we need $m\otimes n$ for each $m\in M,n\in N$ (which is where $M\times N$ comes in), but we also need sums of these things (which is where the free module on $M\times N$ comes into play), but also we want $(a+b)\otimes c=a\otimes c+b\otimes c$, so we quotient by the submodule generated by the differences $(a+b)\otimes c-a\otimes c-b\otimes c$ (and similarly for the right distributive property).

Comment: @anon, are these basis elements "splittable" (obey homomorphism additive property)?

Comment: The relation $(a+b,c)=(a,c)+(b,c)$ is not true in the free module on the set $M\times N$, but it is true in the quotient module (when we mod out by the submodule generated by the differences between the two sides of the equation). Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @anon, no.  I am asking in just the free module $M \times N$ before taking the quotient. I am having a difficult time why we can't "combine things component wise" like u wrote earlier. In some text, we are taking the basis elements $e_{(x,y)}$, but aren't these bilinear? Cuz some text switch back to the $(x,y)$ notation.

Comment: We can't combine things componentwise in the free module on $M\times N$ ... by definition. The free module construction does not care that $M\times N$ is comprised of tuples, for all it cares $M\times N$ has no algebraic structure whatsoever. // I don't know why you think the Kronecker delta functions are supposed to be bilinear functions on $M\times N$.

Comment: Take $M = \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $N = \mathbb{Z}_3$ with $M \times N = \{ (\bar{0}, \bar{0}), (\bar{1}, \bar{0}), (\bar{0}, \bar{1}),(\bar{1}, \bar{1}),(\bar{0}, \bar{2}),(\bar{1}, \bar{2})  \}$. We can't argue say that $(\bar{0}, \bar{0}) + (\bar{0}, \bar{1}) = (\bar{0}, \bar{1})$ for example? I mean the Kronecker Delta is linear when we are just talking about one module (or vector space for simplicity) right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76052/discussion-between-hawk-and-anon).

Comment: The equation $(0,0)+(0,1)=(0,1)$ is true in the module $M\times N$, but if you forget about the addition structure and just treat $M\times N$ as a barren set, then form a free module, the equation is *not* true. Like I said, the free module construction does not care about $M\times N$'s addition operation - it might as well not be there. It's like, the free abelian group on $\mathbb{N}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (as an abelian group), where the natural number $n$ corresponds to the power $x^n$. The equation $1+1=2$ is true in $\mathbb{N}$, but $x+x=x^2$ is not true in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: And no, a Kronecker delta function on a module is definitely not linear.

Comment: @anon, so if $(x,y) = (\bar{0},\bar{0}), (x', y) = (\bar{1}, \bar{0})$, how do we define $(x + x', y)$?

Comment: If $x=0,y=0,x'=1$ then $(x+x',y)$ is $(1,0)$. But $(0,0)+(1,0)$ is not $(1,0)$ in the free module on $M\times N$. Just like how $0+1=1$ in $\Bbb N$ but $1+x\ne x$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

Comment: @anon, why are we taking $1 + x \neq x$ as counter example? In the free module of $M \times N$ (over $\mathbb{N}$ say), my sum should still hold that is $1(\bar{0}, \bar{0}) + 1(\bar{1},\bar{0}) = 1(\bar{1},\bar{0})$

Comment: No, $(0,0)+(1,0)=(1,0)$ does **not** hold. I was using my previous example of how the free abelian group on $\Bbb N$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z[x]$, and we do not have $x^0+x^1=x^1$ because the addition operation in $\Bbb N$ (which would tell us $0+1=1$) is completely irrelevant to the free module on $\Bbb N$. I have told you over and over again that the addition operation on the module $M\times N$ is completely irrelevant to the addition operation in the free module on the set $M\times N$, but you keep not listening to me. Can you explain this repeated disregard for what I'm telling you?

Comment: If it helps, use different symbols for the addition operation in $M\times N$ and the addition operation in $F(M\times N)$, or use different symbols for the elements (like I have been doing with $\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ in $\Bbb N$ versus  $x^0,x^1,x^2,\cdots$ in the free module $F(\Bbb N)\cong\Bbb Z[x]$). So, for instance, you have $$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$$ in $M\times N$ but you have $$e_{(a,b)}+e_{(c,d)}\ne e_{(a+c,b+d)}$$ in $F(M\times N)$.

Comment: Let's say we take $\Bbb N$ again, but let's write the elements using infinite vectors $(x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots)$. The elements of $\Bbb N$ correspond to basis vectors $e_i=(0,\cdots,0,1,0,\cdots)$. Do you think that we have $e_0+e_1=e_1$? Of course not, even though $0+1=1$ in $\Bbb N$. In the free module $F(X)$, the elements of $X$ are simply used to label the basis elements of $F(X)$, any algebraic structure present in $X$ is disregarded for this purpose.

Comment: No I have not been ignoring what you said about the $+$ operation. I didn't address it because I didn't fully understand you mean. All I understood before was that they both have an addition, but in the free Module of $M \times N$, the additive operator is different is what you are saying. In my original post, I wrote that $1 = e_{(x + x',y)}(x + x',y) = e_{(x + x',y)}(x,y) + e_{(x + x',y)}(x',0) = 0$, but I think the reason for the why both sides should be different is entirely different from my reasoning.

Comment: That $1=0$ equation is wrong because Kronecker deltas are not linear (nor are they bilinear for that matter).

Comment: [What about this answer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/78571/26728) It implies the basis are bilinear? Because I've always thought (like you) that the basis just checks whether it identifies with the subscript or not.

Comment: If you pick a basis for a vector space, then the dual basis acts as Kronecker delta functions when *restricted* to the set of basis vectors, but it is **not** a Kronecker delta function on the vector space itself. Assuming $M$ is finite, then the free module $F(M)$ (conceived of as spanned by Kronecker delta functions on $M$) will include elements of the dual module (i.e. linear maps from $M$), but it will also include *all* functions on $M$, linear or not.

Comment: @anon, "but it is not a Kronecker delta function on the vector space itself" by that you mean it checks only basis vectors?

Comment: A linear map from $M$ (such as the dual basis vectors will be) will not be Kronecer delta functions on the space itself. Dual basis vectors will only be Kronecker delta functions on the set of basis vectors. I don't know what you mean by the word "checks."

Comment: Take an infinite module, say $\Bbb Z$. The dual module is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$, which has rank $1$, but the free module $F(\Bbb Z)$ is infinitely generated, having rank $\aleph_0=|\Bbb Z|$ and, moreover, has no intersection with the dual module (other than the identically zero function). The free $\Bbb Z$-module on $M$ (conceived of as spanned by Kronecker delta functions, essentially the set of all functions $M\to\Bbb Z$ with finite support) and the dual module comprised of linear functions $M\to\Bbb Z$ are different beasts.

Comment: Moreoever, to reiterate this again, the free module on $M$ (here, the set of all functions $M\to\Bbb Z$ with finite support) is defined **completely independently** of any algebraic structure on $M$, whereas the dual module (the set of all linear functions $M\to\Bbb Z$) uses the addition operation on $M$ in its definition.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76141/discussion-on-question-by-hawk-let-m-and-n-be-modules-definition-of-m-oti).

Comment: @anon, So I thought about this for a while and this is the best conclusion I could come up with. 

Let $M \times N$ be $A-module$ and $Z = \oplus_{M \times N} A = \{ \sum_{i =1}^n a_i(v_i,w_i): n = |M \times N| \}$ the free module of $M \times N$ over $A$. Every element in $(v_i,w_i) \in M \times N$ contributes one (unique) summand in the sum of $\sum_{i =1}^n a_i(v_i,w_i)$. So in other words, somewhere down the line in this sum, the *basis* elements $(v_1 + v_2,w_1)$, $(v_1,w_1)$, $(v_2,w_1)$ appear

Comment: in $\sum_{i =1}^n a_i(v_i,w_i)$ as a summand (i.e. $a_1(v_1,w_1) + \dots + a_j(v_1 + v_2, w_1) + \dots + a_k(v_2,w_1) +\dots a_n(v_n,w_n)$) to generate stuff in the Free-module. And none of these elements can be written as a sum of each other because they are basis elements. To justify the existence of the Tensor Product, we will require that they "can" be written as a sum of each other (i.e. the bilinear property). Is this an acceptable answer my own question?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations seem to suggest that you believe $f(a,b) + f(c,d) = f(a+c, b+d)$ for a bilinear map $f$, which is incorrect.  The correct property is $f(a,b) + f(c,b) = f(a+c, b)$ (notice that the second component does not change), and a similar equation where the first component does not change.

Comment: Oh right we are considering the "e"s to be bilinear.

Comment: But the bilinear property is still not right

Comment: @Hawk How do you figure?